# Java RESTful Jersey Examples?

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Are there any examples that demonstrate using Java and Jersey to perform Client<->Server communication? Such as sending XML data to and from each other?

Comment: I'm curious what the use case would be where REST is the best tool for sending XML, especially a using a somewhat heavy-weight project like Jersey.

Comment: isn't Jersey's documentation enough?

Comment: Following tutorial is good for beginners. http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/08/jersey-rest-tutorial.html

Answer (score 13):

I would suggest [this tutorial from Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html)

It's great place to start with exploring Java Restful, with the use of Tomcat and Jersey. With small remark that not everything there is cohirant- you should try to do some of the work yourself.

Furthermore I had trouble myself working with it, but I found this [great extension to](http://www.javahotchocolate.com/tutorials/restful.html) the Vogel's tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The one from Lars Vogel already pointed out is great, but I would also recommend you to check [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-aj-tomcat/), published by IBM. Also, the [official documentation](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/index.html) is full of useful  code snipets. This, together with the API reference should be enough to start on it!

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of samples in the Jersey samples zip file:

http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/samples/jersey-samples/1.4/jersey-samples-1.4-project.zip